# CSS3 Colour Transition on Button

Tags: css, colors, css-transitions, transition

I can't seem to get my button to change colour with CSS3 transitions. I've been successful using the roundabout same code on  and  tags, but no such luck with the button.

Here's the code:

```
.button {
    position:absolute;
    width: 135px;
    height: 46px;
    background-color: #ef6529;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #c33b00;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #af5a5a;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #af5a5a;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #af5a5a;
    -webkit-transition:color 1s ease-in;  
    -moz-transition:color 1s ease-in;  
    -o-transition:color 1s ease-in;  
    transition:color 1s ease-in;
}

.button:hover {
    width: 135px;
    height: 46px;
    background-color: #ff6726;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #c33b00;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="button">
    <!--<h2>PUSH ME!</h2>-->
</a>
```

Cheers!

Comment: could you post your html? would be helpful to see the markup

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified colors for the button. I presume you want to transition the background color insted. Just change `transition:color 1s ease-in;` to `transition: background-color 1s ease-in;`.

Comment: Ah, I see! That's why it worked on the other elements because I was just changing the `color` attribute. Specifying `background-color` worked. Thanks!